# How to findviewbyid to an item that hasn't been created yet?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i am creating a Checkbox inside the java code while the program is running like this:

```
void openContactsList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams butparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // getting phone number and name of the contacts
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
            null);
    int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int indexNumber = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
    j = 0;
    people.moveToFirst();
    ContactsDataBase entry = new ContactsDataBase(Contacts.this);
    entry.open();
    do {
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(params);
        for (j = 0; (j < 3) && next; j++) {
            // create the person and put it in the db table
            String name = people.getString(indexName);
            String number = people.getString(indexNumber);
            entry.createEntry(name, number);
            // create every person Image button
            CheckBox btnTag = new CheckBox(this);
            butparams.setMargins(j, 10, 0, 0);
            btnTag.setGravity(10);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(butparams);
            btnTag.setText(number + "\n" + name);
            btnTag.setTextSize(10);
            btnTag.setTag("Button " + name);
            try {
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                btnTag.setId(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // Handle parse error.
            }
            // btnTag.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.have_a_nice_day);
            btnTag.getLayoutParams().width = 70;
            btnTag.getLayoutParams().height = 70;
            next = people.moveToNext();
            row.addView(btnTag);
        }
        layout12.addView(row);
    } while (next);
    entry.close();
    people.close();
}
```

so every checkbox is a person that i saved in my phone and the Id is the phone number
now i want to check if they are checked, and than make a button to move the checked ones to other LinearLayout...  but the problem is that i dont know how to check them if i cant get the Id because the computer cannot find them when they didnt have been created yet and they are not in R.java class yet!
well ,i created a Db on SQL so i got the phone numbers and i tried go one by one . something like that:

```
{ 
    int num; //lets say that the num is the phonenumber=the Id 
    Friends = (CheckBox) findviewbyid(R.id.num)   //this it the problem
    if(Friends.isChecked()){  // and i got one by one on the Db and changing the number
        ...  //all i want to do is here so i wont write it (its not the point here)
    }
}
```

So I can't use this num because its not in the `R.java` 
How can I check those checkboxes. maybe I can search in the program for all of the Id's in a specific `LinearLayout`
Thank you for helping I hope you understand what I want..

Comment: You have to make some kind of array with flags, and when checkboxes get created just set their state. That's the only way.

Comment: why don't you use a listview ?

Comment: Actualy i read something about it, how can i use it and how does it works? can u give me an example please?  can it save the checkboxes state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you can use 10+ digits phone number as View ID(integer). But if it works then you may use

```
Friends = (CheckBox) findviewbyid(phonenumber)
```

Comment: int num = 0;
  try {
   num = Integer.parseInt(phoneNum);
  } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
   // Handle parse error.
  }
like this

Comment: Johny Smith thank you, it works !!! now i just got little problem with the formation but it works thank you all :)